# Very slow browsers after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: 16.10, browser

In this week I upgraded my Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.10 (I updated to 16.04 and then to 16.10).
After this I literally cannot do anything on any browsers (Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Firefox), every action is very slow. Other apps work fine.

Is anyone have any idea?
Is this maybe related with drivers (I have HD7770)?

Comment: How does it work in a 16.10 live session?

Comment: I tried but I can't install other browsers. But I think I haven't any other way than reinstall all system... :/

Comment: I had to go back to 15.10. I don't know, it's weird... :/

Comment: Please don't. Using unsupported EoL releases puts you and evrybody else in danger. Security updates are no longer being installed. At least Firefox is already available in 16.10. The question was/is: Does it work as expected in the said live session? If so then please install it from scratch instead of going through several release upgrades that are prone to error.

Comment: Same problem.. Upon refereshing several times the page gets opened.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, yes, in live session it's the same.

Comment: Since this never had an answer, and 16.10 is now EOL, I'm flagging to close.